# Integration of normal probability distribution function with random numbers

Tags: matlab

```
function Y=normpdf(X)
syms X
Y = normpdf(X);
int(Y,X,1,inf)
end
```

I need to integrate normal pdf function from 1 to infinity for the case of N=100 where N is the total numbers generated.I know i need to use randn() for generating random numbers but i dont know how to use it in this situation.

Comment: For clarification, why symbolic, and why infinity and not the highest number you got from your N trials? Also, the PDF doesn't change with N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have `N = 100` random numbers from `t = randn(N, 1);`. First, we sort with `t = sort(t)`, then the integrated PDF, i.e. cumulative density function is approximated by your samples with `p = (1 : N) / N` for `t` as you can see with `plot(t, p)`. It will overlap well with `hold on, plot(t, normcdf(t), 'r')`.

Comment: +1 Nice approach. You surely mean `plot(t, normcdf(t), 'r').`

Answer (score 1):

A perhaps more intuitive approach is to partition the x axis into bins in order to estimate the CDF:

```
N = 100; % number of samples
t = randn(N, 1); % random data
x = linspace(-10,10,200); % define bins
estim_cdf = mean(bsxfun(@le, t, x)); % estimate CDF
plot(x, estim_cdf);
hold on
plot(x, normcdf(x), 'r')
```

[image]

Note that @s.bandara's solution can be interpreted as the limiting case of this as the number of bins tends to infinity, and therefore it probably gives more accurate results.

Comment: +1 more intuitive. You could think of my solution as optimally adaptive binning.