# how plot complementary cumulative density function (CCDF) of data points?

Tags: matlab, statistics

suppose i have data points as:

```
a=2.3; 
b=5.3;
n=2000; % number of data blocks
data=a+(b-a)*rand(1,1000); % data points
x=[1:.1:7]; % x-axis
```

How to plot the Complementary Cumulative Density Function (CCDF) of this data for such 2000 data blocks ? Any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Following the same approach as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19797251/integration-of-normal-probability-distribution-function-with-random-numbers/19797454#19797454) to a similar question, you can plot the CCDF of `data` like this:

   ```
   plot(sort(data), linspace(1-1/length(data), 0, length(data)))
   ```

   This gives the CCDF value (between 0 and 1) at each of the data points, by simply counting the proportion of values greater than that value (that's the `linspace` part: for the first point, all values are greater except for one, ..., for the last point no values are greater).

   [image]
2. If you need the CCDF at a *fixed* set of `x` points, use the approach of [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19797251/integration-of-normal-probability-distribution-function-with-random-numbers/19800905#19800905) to that question:

   ```
   x = [1:.1:7];
   y = mean(bsxfun(@gt, data.', x));
   plot(x, y)
   ```

   Now `y` is the proportion of values greater than each point in `x`. In this case that proportion has to be explicitly determined, and this is done efficiently with `bsxfun`.

[image]

Comment: :Your code works perfectly,But could we also plot the CCDF using this relation: CCDF=1-CDF.